# Interrupting a German research fellowship

Tags: research-process, funding, germany

I am going to accept a research fellowship in Germany for the duration of 24 months.

In the Guideline, it is written that (in English)

> Interruption to take advantage of another fellowship in Germany or a third country is usually not possible.

I came from Italy and my plan is to continue there my academic career. My question is the following:

Can I interrupt the granted fellowship before the two years to take advantage of an Italian RTD-a (it is a short-term research position of the duration of 3 years)? Is an RTD-a considered a research fellowship?

Thank you!

Comment: You can quit the German fellowship to take the Italian one, but ‘interrupting’ to go elsewhere for 3 years is unlikely at best…

Comment: @JonCuster Ah ok! I misunderstood the word "interruption". Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Interrupting* the German research fellowship would mean something like taking the German fellowship for a year, then being on some other fellowship, and afterwards returning to complete the second year of the German fellowship. The default assumption for any kind of academic position would be that interrupting it in this way is **not possible**, and the language in the rules here is just to reinforce this default assumption. In particular, this is definitely not saying that you can interrupt the German fellowship for something that does not count as a fellowship.

On the other hand, ending research fellowships early is common (as aligning end and start dates perfectly will not always be possible). Some fellowship schemes have restrictions on this, in particular if the manner of ending it early would interfere with the intended goal of the fellowship scheme. However, in absence of such language my default assumption would be that it is possible to end the fellowship early.